# Exclude tables in the Par file during export in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, export, par

I have below export command for exporting the schema and which works fine in command prompt.

```
exp RATOR_MONITORING/RATOR_MONITORING@10.127.666.777/O2P0RTE PARFILE=exp02_rm.par
```

The exp02_rm.par file has below information:

```
OWNER=RATOR_MONITORING
LOG=exp02_rm.log
FILE=exp02_rm.dmp
INDEXES=Y
CONSTRAINTS=Y
GRANTS=Y
COMPRESS=Y
FULL=N
ROWS=Y
CONSISTENT=Y
BUFFER=102035256
FEEDBACK=500
```

Now i want to exclude few tables i.e `KPI_LOGS,ALERT_LOGS` which i dont want to export.But really dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how to excludes the table in the PAR file. But you can use `TABLES` option in the PAR file and include the name of the tables you can to export.

```
OWNER=RATOR_MONITORING
LOG=exp02_rm.log
FILE=exp02_rm.dmp
TABLES=KPI_LOGS,ALERT_LOGS
INDEXES=Y
CONSTRAINTS=Y
GRANTS=Y
COMPRESS=Y
FULL=N
ROWS=Y
CONSISTENT=Y
BUFFER=102035256
FEEDBACK=500
```